# Convert String to JavaRDD<String>

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, mapreduce

I want to make some computation on each text file from directory,  and then use the results to compute another value.

To read files from directory I use:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> textFiles = sc.wholeTextFiles(PATH);
```

Next, for each file

```
textFiles.foreach(file -> processFile(file));
```

I want to make some magic like computing frequent words.
I have an access to the path of the file and its content.

JavaRDD offers methods such as flatMap, mapToPair, reduceByKey which I need.
The question is, is there any way to convert the value of the JavaPairRDD to JavaRDD?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012068/convert-javapairrdd-to-javardd

Comment: why would you want to convert JavaPairRDD to JavaRDD when you need both the path and the data? when you read the file using wholeTextFiles, the first element of JavaPairRDD is the path to the file and second element is the actual data. So I think your intention of converting JavaPairRDD to JavaRDD is a bad idea

Comment: by calling textFile i got JavaRDD<> which contains each line of file as a separate object. Calling wholeTextFiles, next converting it to JavaRDD by JavaRDD newRdd = textFiles.map(x -> x._2); i got whole file in one object. Can I somehow convert it to have each line as a separate object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is, is there any way to convert the value of the JavaPairRDD to JavaRDD?

```
textFiles.keys(); //Return an RDD with the keys of each tuple.
textFiles.values(); // Return an RDD with the values of each tuple.
```

*** UPDATE:

As per your updated question, I think the below achieves what you need. I created two CSV files in a directory "tmp".

one.csv:

```
one,1
two,2
three,3
```

two.csv:

```
four,4
five,5
six,6
```

Then ran the following code LOCALLY:

```
String appName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
SparkConf sc = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);

JavaPairRDD<String, String> fS = jsc.wholeTextFiles("tmp");

System.out.println("File names:");
fS.keys().collect().forEach(new Consumer<String>(){
    public void accept(String t)
    {
        System.out.println(t);
    }});

System.out.println("File content:");
fS.values().collect().forEach(new Consumer<String>(){
    public void accept(String t)
    {
        System.out.println(t);
    }});    
jsc.close();
```

It produces the following output (I removed all unnecessary Spark output and edited my directory paths)

```
File names:
file:/......[my dir here]/one.csv
file:/......[my dir here]/two.csv
File content:
one,1
two,2
three,3
four,4
five,5
six,6
```

Seems like this is what you were asking for...

Comment: textFiles.values() returns JavaRDD which contains each whole file as a separate "object".
Can I somehow convert it to JavaRDD containing each line of that file as a separate "object"?

Comment: I just created two CSV files in a directory and used some simple code to print out its content -- see the updated answer